# RelativeLayout Background isn't properly aligned

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to set up a background for my MainActivity in Android Studio, but it doesn't align properly on the top.

I've tried changing the device from Nexus 6P to Nexus 5 and Nexus 4 but it always looks the same.

This picture may help you understand the problem:

[image]

As you can see the gray triangle should be aligned at the top but there is a white line in the middle that I don't know how to remove.

This is my code, I'd really appreciate some help to fix this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="dancam.com.myapp.MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried also to set the `android:layout_height` to `fill_parent` but nothing changed

The theme that I'm using is *Light_NoTitleBar*

Comment: Try removing all the padding

Comment: @OutOfRange unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: I tried it in my Android Studio. It looks exactly like what you are expecting.

Comment: @OutOfRange I tried to refresh and also restart Android Studio but it still looks the same... What setting have you tried it with?

Comment: Check out the screenshot: http://imgur.com/Za0Fmsc. Try running in actual device or an emulator.

Comment: Same problem also in the emulator :( what theme are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115557/discussion-between-outofrange-and-daniele).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Image I was using had a transparent gap above the gray triangle that caused the problem. 
When I opened the image in android studio I was able to see the gap. Make sure you crop your images the right way!